# Sending large video files to WebDav Server from iOS device

Tags: ios, video, stream, webdav, video-recording

How can we send large video files to WebDav Server from iOS app. Basically I am trying to record the video and need to send it to the WebDav Server. Do I need to send as a streaming video? What are the complexities that we need to consider while sending the large video files to WebDav server. I searched for solution but no luck so far. Do we need to use any WebDav clients available for iOS to send video files to WebDav Server ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload the video after it has finished recording then its an ordinary PUT which you can do with any webdav client. The size of the file is only an issue to the extent that size is for any type of file.

If you want to upload as its being recorded then thats quite difficult because most video formats have header information which cant be produced until the end of file is reached.
So if your requirement is to upload progressively you might need to encode to HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) which emits self contained video chunks (usually 3 second segments) and a playlist file that HLS clients know how to use to reassemble as a single continuous playback.

This is an efficient way to enable almost live one-to-many video streaming through a webdav server. I've implemented it on [kademi.co](http://www.kademi.co), works a treat